# MySql query to pull data in matrix form from database

Tags: mysql, matrix

I have data in database with two columns name and year. Something like this,

```
name | year
-----------
tim  | 2001
ron  | 2002
tim  | 2003
ron  | 2005
tim  | 2004
pol  | 2002
pol  | 2001
tim  | 2003
pol  | 2004
tim  | 2002
```

I want to output the result matrix something like this.

```
      tim | pol | ron
2001   1  |  1  |  0
2002   1  |  1  |  1
2003   2  |  0  |  0
2004   1  |  1  |  0
2005   0  |  0  |  1
```

tim | pol | ron is arranged in descending order based on cumulative sum i.e tim(5), pol(3), ron(2).

Data is not limited to tim,pol,ron. There can be n-different names.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  year,
  SUM(name='tim') tim,
  SUM(name='pol') pol,
  SUM(name='ron') ron
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
   year
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4438/3).

**EDIT:** if you need a dynamic query because the exact number of values could vary, you could use a prepared statement like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('SELECT year,',
  GROUP_CONCAT(sums),
  ' FROM yourtable GROUP BY year')
FROM (
SELECT CONCAT('SUM(name=\'', name, '\') AS `', name, '`') sums
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) s
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4438/29).

Comment: Data is not limited to tim,pol,ron. There can be n-different names.

Comment: @JohnGalt the pivot in mysql is static so you have to build the query yourself using the n columns you need

Comment: @JohnGalt mysql doesn't have a pivot function, but you can create a dynamic query, please see my updated answer

Comment: @fthiella SQL Fiddle solution is perfect. I tried to recreate this in wamp phpmyadmin and getting an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'year' in 'field list'  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following then at the presentation layer transpose it.

```
SELECT yourtable.year, Hits.name, Hits.hit
FROM yourtable
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
 year, name, count(*) as hit
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
   year, name) AS Hits ON yourtable.year = Hits.year
GROUP BY yourtable.year, yourtable.name
```

**It lacks** no-hits, i.e. those names that don't fall in a certain year, i.e. you won't see any **0**.

Answer (score 0):

While fthiella's approach is the most common way to build a pivot table, you may want to try this query, which is faster in most cases:

```
SELECT
  years.year,
  COALESCE(tim.c, 0) AS tim,
  COALESCE(pol.c, 0) AS pol,
  COALESCE(pol.c, 0) AS ron
FROM (SELECT year FROM yourtable GROUP BY year) AS years
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(name) AS c, year FROM yourtable WHERE name = 'tim' GROUP BY year
) AS tim ON (tim.year = years.year)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(name) AS c, year FROM yourtable WHERE name = 'pol' GROUP BY year
) AS pol ON (pol.year = years.year)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(name) AS c, year FROM yourtable WHERE name = 'ron' GROUP BY year
) AS ron ON (ron.year = years.year)
GROUP BY years.year;
```

This is a bit more painful to write, and to perform well, it requires two indexes:

- a two-columns index on both fields used as column and row discriminant, in this order (ie. in your case, on `(name, year)` in this order)
- an index on the row discriminant (ie. in your case, on `(year)`)

But the larger the result (either more rows or more columns or both), the faster it performs compared to the usual approach. I posted some [sample data here](http://spiritlink.free.fr/thetable.sql.gz) if anyone feels like playing with it. The [corresponding queries are here](http://spiritlink.free.fr/queries.sql).